# Null in directory name does not return exception when it is created

Tags: c#

I just encountered a situation where a colleague is creating directories from a list.  It just so happens that one of the items in the list is null but an exception is not null.

To satisfy my curiosity, I wrote a test program to mimic what he was doing.  This test programo attempts to create a null directory in c:\Temp, which already exists.  I would've expected a Null Exception to be thrown but no exception was thrown.

Here's my test program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace CreateNullDirectory
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String DirectoryName = null;

        String FullDirectoryName = string.Format("c:\\Temp\\{0}",DirectoryName);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Creating Directory {0}", FullDirectoryName));

        try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FullDirectoryName);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Successfully created directory {0}", FullDirectoryName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error creating {0} - {1}", FullDirectoryName, ex.Message));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Is CreateDirectory ignoring the terminating null and I'm only attempting to create C:\Temp which already exists?

Comment: A `null` value passed into a `String.Format` call results in an empty string instead.

Comment: Why don't you delete "C:\Temp" and then you can test the theory yourself?

Comment: From the documentation on String.Format, "If object is null, the format item is replaced with String.Empty." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're doing is calling `Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Temp")`, because passing a null value in format string returns `string.Empty`.

`CreateDirectory` either creates the directory if it doesn't exist, or does nothing if it already exists.

Comment: As a follow up, here are the list of exceptions that can happen from that call: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx